# PostgreSQL - How to set temporary variables inside a function trigger that can later be used for INSERT INTO?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I am very new to PostgreSQL and I figured I could benefit from the communities help on this one. I'm struggling to get this concept to work.

All it is supposed to do is insert data into dimension tables if the data does not already exist. Then returns the dimension ID for later use. Errors fall within a CASE statement because I also want to assign a boolean value to `success` by if an error was present or not. (EDIT: Here, when I say "error", I am referring to a field in the data).

The error I get states that `time_stamp` does not exist. I thought I read that INSERT INTO RETURNING INTO would implicitly create a temp table though. Seems I must have misunderstood though. Is anyone able to help me find the correct logic here? Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION distribute_process_data() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$ 
BEGIN
    select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() into time_stamp;

    INSERT INTO
        sources(source, category)
        VALUES(NEW.source, NEW.category) ON CONFLICT (source) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO source_id;

    INSERT INTO
        mediums(sources_id, medium)
        VALUES(source_id, NEW.medium) ON CONFLICT (sources_id, medium) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO medium_id;

    INSERT INTO
        countries(country)
        VALUES(NEW.country) ON CONFLICT (country) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO country_id;

    INSERT INTO
        requests(sources_id, request)
        VALUES(source_id, NEW.request) ON CONFLICT (request) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id INTO request_id;

    CASE
        WHEN NEW.error IS NOT NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO
                errors(timestamp, processes_id, error)
                VALUES(time_stamp, NEW.id, error)
                RETURNING id INTO error_id;
            select FALSE INTO success;
        ELSE
            select NULL INTO error_id;
            select TRUE INTO success;
    END CASE;

    INSERT INTO
        processes(
            id, timestamp, requests_id, errors_id, sources_id, mediums_id, countries_id, successful,
            date, web_visits, conversions, ad_impressions, ad_clicks, ad_cost, site1_ad_visits,
            site2_ad_visits, site1_ad_visits_bounce_rate, downloads_desktop, downloads_mobile,
            initiated_registrations, completed_registrations, paid_users, revenue
        )
        VALUES(
            NEW.id, time_stamp, request_id, error_id, medium_id, country_id, success,
            NEW.date, NEW.web_visits, NEW.conversions, NEW.ad_impressions, NEW.ad_clicks, NEW.ad_cost,
            NEW.site1_ad_visits, NEW.site2_ad_visits, NEW.site1_ad_visits_bounce_rate, 
            NEW.downloads_desktop, NEW.downloads_mobile, NEW.initiated_registrations, NEW.completed_registrations, 
            NEW.paid_users, NEW.revenue
        )

    RETURN new;

END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

I tried using the code provided. It did not work, stating that my "variables" do not exist.
I was expecting it to complicity create them.

It may be worth mentioning, I'd favoring readability over speed here, since I'm still a new user and will be in charge of maintaining the code.

Comment: Read the docs [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) and [Declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Are we sure declarations will work for my use case? Is says something about the declaration needing to occur within certain locations.

For reference, I don't know the variables values until after insert. The ID is auto-incremented, and I am extracting the ID after insert.

Comment: 1) Read the plpgsql structures link, look at the examples in the declarations link. 2)  You **have to** declare all variables and their associated type, either in the function arguments or the `DECLARE` section,  before you can use them. 3) Since this a trigger function arguments really don't enter into it as they will all be `text`, so you will need to use `DECLARE`.

Comment: I see. That was actually quite the easy fix. I just declared the variables and added a missing semicolon at the end. It accepted the function. I'll still read through these links though. I usually read though documentation firsthand, but today I've been having quite a bit of mental fatigue and reading has been the bane of my shift thus far. Thanks still. I found my solution with your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of storing variables out of the trigger other than a table or Session variables that are to expensive and dangerous.
A temporary table in other hand is very handy and common usage of temporary files also .

Almost every time the storage cost is less expensive than the cache cost for larger servers that usually have big amount of engineering on top of whether or not a query should use the cache and when.

A example of it is dynamic SQL used for queries that doesn't get executed multiple times instead of static queries that uses the cache all the time, once the postgres cache limit is reached previous cached queries get reindexed and the database gets very slow,dynamic sql in other hand executes without cache, are slower and affordable to the right situations.

You could try some validations about the table structure using the information schema before

```
IF SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='countries' AND table_schema='public' IS NULL THEN
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE countries ADD column'|| **column_name** ||' TIMESTAMP; '
ELSE
    EXECUTE  'INSERT INTO countries ('||column_name||') VALUES( now() )';
END IF;
```

There is no other way out for manipulating results without error due to non-existing objects other than Dynamic SQL.

There is another way you can use Returning syntax to achieve easier, performant and dynamic using WITH, the code below is possible to interpolate the results avoiding declare unique variables, also binds the process to each other results :

```
WITH query1 AS (
    SELECT 'val' AS var ),
query2 AS (
    INSERT INTO test (name) SELECT query1.var FROM query1 RETURNING id 
),
query3 AS (
    DELETE FROM test WHERE id = (SELECT query2.id FROM query2 )
)
    SELECT * FROM query1 ;
```